# Prove that the product of a continuous vector valued function and a continuous scalar function is continuous.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Let

$f:D\subseteq R\to R^N$

$g:D\subseteq R\to R$

where both functions are continuous at $p.$

I am asked to prove that 
$(fg)(x)$ is continuous at $p$.

Since $(fg)(x)=(f_i(x)g(x),...,f_n(x)g(x))$ where $f_i$ is the coordinate function.

I also know that 
$$\left\| X-Y\right\| ^2=\sum _{i=1}^n \left(x_i-y_i\right){}^2$$

Now this is what I thought:

To prove that $(fg)(x)$ is continuous it would mean that I could prove that for any $\epsilon$>0 there exists a K element of the natural numbers such that

$\left\| f (x_k)g(x_k) -f(p)g(p)\right\| <\epsilon$ whenever k>K.

Now that would mean that it would be sufficient to prove that:

$\left\| f (x_k)g(x_k) -f(p)g(p)\right\| {}^2=\sum _{i=1}^n \left(f _i(x_k)g(x_k)-f (p)g(p)\right){}^2<\epsilon{}$ whenever k>K

and as f and g are continuous I have that

$||f(x_k)-f(p)||<\epsilon{}$

$||g(x_k)-g(p)||<\epsilon{}$

whenever k>K

Next: choose any $\epsilon{}>0$

To each $i=1,...,n$ there corresponds a number $K_i$ element of the naturals such that $abs(f_i(x_k)-f_i(p))<\epsilon$

to each $i$ there exists a $K_i$ such that

$abs((f i (x k )-f i (p ))(g(x k )-g (p )))))<\epsilon$$

now if I choose $K=max(K_i)$ then I thought I could continue by constructing 
$\epsilon$ such that multipling by n and squaring would allow me to sum up however, I am stuck with the

$-f i (x k )g (p ) -f i (p )g(x k )$ and I cant move on. Could someone take me through the steps, preferable continue with where I left of, or a couple of steps earlier. However, if what I have done is completely fruitless ore wrong any solution would do.

Comment: Do you know that a function $f : D \subset \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$ is continuous if and only if the coordinate functions $f_i : D \to \mathbb R$ are all continuous?

Comment: Yes I do know that.

Comment: If you know the fact mentioned by Umberto P. then you just need to prove that $f_i \cdot g$ is continuous for each $i$. But then $f_i$ is obviously continuous

Comment: To prove $f_ig$ is continuous, do you have to use $\epsilon$-$\delta$ or can you use the fact that the limit of a product equals the product of the limits?

Comment: @JohnDouma Yes, in first instance I would like to use this, but if it is not possible then I am open for alternative options.